# Reading .props of a react element - with plain javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-dom

I have a react dom of a 3rd party website and by using (injecting) a content script in that page, I want to reach `.props.data` value of some elements.

[image]

I am watching the mutations and I can catch every time each list item changes

Is there a way to read these values using console with plain javascript or maybe with jQuery? Are there any ways to read `.props.` values?

Comment: you might want to block out the adAccountID on the right side panel as well under Props.

Comment: woops. missed it. cheers

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but if you just want to see the properties of a component, you can do the following for a class: console.log(this) in your render() method and you will get the complete component in the console. It's really just a javascript object. For a stateless functional component you could add console.log(arguments) above the return statement.

Comment: Hi @KyleRichardson, my script is plain javascript that is inserted into a 3rd party website (facebook), and I don't have react in my script, instead the facebook website (components) is built in react. My question is, is there a way to see the react props of an element using something like: `$0.props.data` in the console? or maybe: `$(el).attr('props')` etc

Comment: From just the rendered DOM element? No.

Comment: From the actual html element? using the chrome console?

Comment: I suppose it's possible, since React Dev Tools exists, as well as other Chrome extensions I've seen that can interact with rendered React components on the page. Perhaps looking at the source code of those tools will provide clues.

Comment: Do those work when you don't have access to the react script?

Comment: @jered can you please refer any? -Kyle, yes probably because you can inject a js script in the html of that page with a chrome extension.

Comment: @senty fair point... :) https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

Comment: I have no clue :(